# How to correctly subtype dict so that MyPy recognizes it as generic?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a subclass of dict:

```py
class MyDict(dict):
    pass
```

Later I use the definition:

```py
my_var: MyDict[str, int] = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

MyPy complains:

```
error: "MyDict" expects no type arguments, but 2 given  [type-arg]
```

How can I define MyDict so that MyPy recognizes it as generic with two type arguments?

I have tried deriving from `typing.Dict` and adding protocol `MutableMapping`, both to no avail.

Comment: There are examples of this in https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule you can remember to ***always* provide type arguments to generic types**, regardless of context. (Remember: [*explicit is better than implicit*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/).)

This means in annotations (e.g. `d: dict[str, int]`) **and** when subclassing (e.g. `class MyDict(dict[str, int]): ...`).

If you want to retain genericity in terms of some or all type parameters of the base class in your own subclass, then pass type variables in place of specific type arguments:

```py
from collections.abc import Hashable
from typing import TypeVar

K = TypeVar("K", bound=Hashable)
V = TypeVar("V")


class MyDict(dict[K, V]):
    ...


class MyStrKeyDict(dict[str, V]):
    ...


class MyIntValDict(dict[K, int]):
    ...


x: MyDict[str, int]
y: MyStrKeyDict[int]
z: MyIntValDict[str]
```

The reason MyPy told you it did not expect any type arguments for `MyDict` is that it implicitly assumed `MyDict` is a subclass of `dict[Any, Any]` because you did not specify the type arguments.

Side note: It would still be **wrong** to now assign e.g. `x = {"a": 1}` as you did in your example because `dict` is not a subtype of `MyDict`. This is why it is usually preferable to subclass the ABC (in this case `Mapping` or `MutableMapping`) or use [protocols](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/).